# How to connect two laptops via USB 3.0 cable?

Tags: usb

I have here an old Win 7 laptop with damaged screen and I'm trying to access it's harddrive from another Win 10 laptop via USB cable (it has a solid bottom cover that I can't remove to physically take out the HDD so that's my only 
way to check it out..)
However when I plug in I get this [pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4Ccc.png)

My question is: is plugging the USB cable enough per itself under normal circumstances to access another laptop's storage (so I can blame it here on possibly damaged HDD) or is there something else to be done in order to establish connection?

Comment: Connecting two computers via USB is not a normal operation and USB, by itself, is not the correct tool for the job. First, you need to tell us WHAT USB device you're using to connect the computers, and second, that USB device will have to be a device designed to perform the specific function of allowing the HDD of one computer to be accessed by the other computer.

Comment: Also, what are the specific models of these two computers?

Comment: A USB 3.0 cable from a HDD Enclosure package.
Two ASUS Vivobook laptops.

Comment: Then no, that cable will not work for you to accomplish this unless you find specific software that enables that connection. USB is not a networking protocol for connections among peers. USB connections all have master/slave relationships, and computers all try to be the Master and assume the item at the other end of the connection is the slave.

Comment: The next part of the problem is that, for most cases, using USB is more complicated than other methods. For a USB connection to work it'll probably have to pretend to create a small private network between the two devices, which would require you to work on the computer with the broken screen to configure its connection to that "network". While you most likely have a network already which the two computers are already connected to, and so why go through the expense and bother of buying the right connectors and setting them up when you can just set up a network share using the existing network.

Comment: BUT, all that said, you really should further explore removing the hard drive from the laptop because if the screen is really broken and the computer unusable, removing the hard drive is the simplest method of accomplishing what you want, even if the laptop doesn't have a dedicated port you can open to find the hard drive: https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Asus+VivoBook+Q200E-BHI3T45+Hard+Drive+Replacement/72015

Comment: _music2myear_ is absolutely right; PC-USB-PC rarely works and is slow as molasses. Open up the borked PC, remove the drive from the damaged PC, put it on a USB-SATA cable, and attach it to a working PC, then copy its data into the working PC. BTW, which of the literally hundred https://www.asus.com/Laptops/VivoBook-Series-Products/ Asus Vivobook models are we talking about? Click [edit] and add to the bottom of your question the model number from the serial number plate. If we have that, we may be able to find instructions for you.

Comment: If your laptop just have a broken screen and still boots into something, there should be extra VGA connector where you can attach an external monitor. More, you should be able to boot it into some stand-alone Linux-based OS via CD-ROM or USB pen drive.